# Is there a lib(cross-platform) to handling operating system date?

Tags: c++, c, date, operating-system

I'm looking for a cross-platform(works at UNIX-like and Windows) library to handling operating system date. Is there it for C programmers? or C++ if really have no for C. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. Normally the functions in `time.h` are used. Are you looking for timezone conversion? Higher precision than seconds? Setting the date? What?

Comment: @R..: I need to update/change the date of OS from a date that I get from internet.

Comment: This is not something you can do in a platform-independent way, and in fact something some platforms may not allow you to do **at all**. If the purpose of your program is date synchronization (note: you'll have a damn hard time doing a better job than existing NTP approaches) then it makes sense to be doing this, but a bulk of your program is going to be handling the **how** of doing it on each platform you want to support. If the purpose of your program is something else and date setting is only tangential, you really should not be attempting it at all; just document that NTP client is req'd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you should try [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time.html).